# @click while displaying menuList VUE2.0

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Im working on a project which using particular framework of VUE2.0. As i wish to do an onclick function on MENU-FOOD then display list of item on food like burger , chicken wings , salad etc. How do we do this on displayMenu() function ? Kindly advice

Example :

MENU-FOOD
    burger
    chicken wings
    salad 
MENU-DRINKS
MENU-BAR

HTML VUE :

```
<div id="app">
        <aside id="side-center">
            <ul id="asideList" class="asideList">
                <li id="nav01">
                    <div class="navmenu" @click="displayMenu()">MENE-FOOD</div>
                    <div id="side-left">
                        <ul>
                            <li v-for="item in groceryList" v-bind:todo="item">{item.text}</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li><div class="navmenu">MENU-DRINKS</div></li>
                <li><div class="navmenu">MENU-BAR</div></li> 
            </ul>
        </aside>
    </div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
 groceryList: [{
                text:'BURGER',
                text:'CHICKEN WING',
                text:'SALAD'
            }],

 displayMenu: function() {
              HOW DO WE DO THIS ?
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the way you define `groceryList`. When you have the same key `text` in your object, the last value rewrites all preceding.

As a result, your `groceryStore` is equal to `[{"text":"SALAD"}]`

Put names into an array, or give uniq keys for your items.

Comment: `{text1: '...', text2: '...'}` but I guess in your case you can just do an array `['BURGER', 'CHICKEN WING', 'SALAD']`